# why nothing happens when booting through usb?

Tags: reinstalling

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 in my laptop. I was playing around with installing apps and softwares. Now i know what i want in my laptop and wanted to start with a clean ubuntu 13.10.
I created bootable USB stick under Ubuntu. Followed the instructions via startup disk creator. Then when i restart my laptop, it stays blank for awhile. I guess i get worried quick.. hehe.. is that normal? Should i just leave it as it will reinstall itself?

Comment: change boot order to usb in bios.

Answer (score 0):

no it won't check your BIOS setting and enable booting from USB.

If thats already done, i suspect there is some problem with the USB boot disc you created, you may want to recreate a new one, or rather try CD installation method.